# Unable to install vmware tools and get VM full-screen

Tags: vmware-player, vmware-tools

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 with VMware player 6 and I cannot get the VM to full screen or install the VMware tools on the VM. The VM is Windows 7. any ideas on how to full screen the VM?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get full screen, you need to install VMware tools.  Install VMware Tools from the VMware Workstation menu, and you are ready to begin the installation process.  The image below shows Reinstall, because the tools are already installed.  In your case it would be Install VMware Tools.

[image]